# SSRS 2008 - Textbox RTF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have rtf text stored in our database that looks like the following:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}  {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang1033\f0\fs22 Some Text Here \f1   \par }
```

It is my understanding that SSRS 2008 should be able to properly display this on a report.  Has anyone been able to have this display correctly?

Robert Bruckner's Advanced Reporting Services Blog

A new feature of SSRS:

Leverage the enhanced Textbox (aka "RichText") to define mixed formatting within the same textbox.  In addition, HTML strings of text can be imported into the report from a database or other source.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, did more research and turns out this is not available in SSRS 2008.  I did get it to work by referencing my own assembly that uses the System.Windows.Forms RichTextBox.  I'll try to post later.

Thanks..

Comment: Hi. Did you actually manage to get a printed report include RTF ?